# Pointer arithmetic - Identical expressions?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2008

Are the result of these expressions identical?

```
&(*ptr) += 4 // Expression 1
ptr += 4 // Expression 2
```

I am mainly a Java developer and have been tasked to recompile an old project from VS2008 to VS2015. The first line above results in a compile error due to the left operand not being a modifiable l-value. The question is if I can use the second expression instead of the first one, since from what I understand they should be identical?

The ptr is of type `char*`.

Would be very thankful for any insight and/or help on this issue.

Comment: So, are you saying that the first _did_ compile under VS2008? If it did, the compiler was doing something non-standard and it's not obvious whether it would have actually changed the value of `ptr` or changed the value of a temporary pointer and thrown that result away. I advise caution.

Comment: It did yes. I find it troubling as well, now knowing that the first expression isn't accessible by the compiler. Afraid I will be correcting something that has been working "broken" all along.

Comment: The first one is ridiculous, honestly I've no idea what the point would of been, I think we need more context. They wouldn't be identical because as the compiler says the first attempts to modify a temporary address, if it were to compile it would presumably have no effect on `ptr`, but you could always use the old compiler and see for yourself.

Comment: @Ron: Apparently, the first expression _did_ compile. That's why this is hard to answer. You'll need to figure out what VS2008 did with it. If it modified a temporary and then immediately discarded the temporary, expression 2 is _not_ a correct replacement.

Comment: @MSalters: Thank you, I will compare the two versions once I have the new one up and running. Actually turned into an interesting problem now.

Comment: Sure that the code you refer to is C++ and not C? C standard defines that `&(*ptr)` will neglect both `&` and `*` operator (though the fact that the result is not an lvalue remains, but maybe that's a compiler bug then)...

Comment: @StephanLechner, `&(*ptr)` is valid in C++ is well ( the result of * is an lvalue ); of course += is not.

Answer (score 1):

`&` returns the address of an lvalue but in itself is not modifiable so `(&a)++` doesn't make sense since you cant assign to `&a`. So the first expression is not a defined operation. (Hence the error that left operand is not a modifiable lvalue). Also `&(*ptr) = ptr` since your are de-referencing a pointer and then grabbing the address, while `&(*ptr)` is a valid syntax construct it is pretty pointless. the second statement moves the pointer over 4 memory addresses.

So no the statements are not the same.

EDIT:
Interesting that it compiled on VS2008. The compiler must of defined `&` as a modifiable value (essentially just creating a pointer off of the address). This was probably just a bug in the compiler. If you need to convert the code to be syntactically correct then the second expression should do just fine. Assuming that you want the end result for ptr to be modified. (Which since the statement uses +=, i feel that was the wanted semantics).